# Alfresco Share - RSS Feeds

Tags: alfresco-share

I am trying to create an RSS feed from my blog onto the RSS Dashlet, for some unknown reason the dashlet doesnt pick up / recognise the URL and so appears no news item.

Any one have any ideas?